# Xamarin C# , I Cant Run Plugin.BLE Codes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make a very simple and basic mobile app for controlling my Arduino with Bluetooth.
Don't have many C# experiences, but it was going well until the Bluetooth part comes.
I've searched everywhere and found this https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le
and started to do instructions in the readme. But I've got errors every time.

first, I copied these codes to androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

after that, I added these codes to mainpage.xml.cs

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
        var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
        var state = ble.State;
    }
}
```

But that caused 2 errors: Error CS0103  The name 'CrossBluetoothLE' does not exist in the current context   BlueT

and I added using Plugin.BLE; so errors disappeared. and I continued to write;

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s,a) => deviceList.Add(a.Device);
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

after I paste these, I got that errors:

> Error CS4033  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async
> method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and
> changing its return type to 'Task
> Error CS0103  The name 'deviceList' does not exist in the current
> context

I tried everything but couldn't solve this problem, and I'm sorry like I said, don't have many # or Android programming experiences, just want to send these slider and button data to my Arduino:
[This is my mobile controller app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07RS.jpg)

Comment: these are pretty basic C# errors you should be able to easily google.  You may also want to read an intro C# book like https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/csharp

Comment: Please see [Async and Await](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/).